# Deprecated function(Graphql module) warning coming after upgrade php vesion from 7.4 to 8.1 in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, graphql, drupal-modules, drupal-9

This error (related to graphql module) is coming in our drupal website after upgrade php 8.1:

Deprecated function: Return type of Drupal\graphql\Plugin\TypePluginManagerAggregator::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in include() (line 5 of /code/web/modules/contrib/graphql/src/Plugin/TypePluginManagerAggregator.php).

when I hite the url domain/update.php/selection.

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Of course, you have upgraded the GraphQL module to the latest version (4.4) before asking?

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you are using Drupal GraphQL in version 3.x and you should migrate to 4.x to have compatibility with newer PHP version. The problem is in [this file](https://github.com/drupal-graphql/graphql/blob/8.x-3.x/src/Plugin/TypePluginManagerAggregator.php), which had last commit almost 5 years ago...

There is [existing issue](https://github.com/drupal-graphql/graphql/issues/1297) and [pull request](https://github.com/drupal-graphql/graphql/pull/1298) about this, but it seems to be inactive a bit.

If you cannot upgrade library, try use a tip from pull request - enforce base graphql library version in `composer.json` and apply patches - author of that comment says that it worked.